# How to set window to always on top using AutoHotKey v2?

Tags: autohotkey, always-on-top

I need to write a script to make the active window always on top, but all the examples are for AutoHotKey v1. How can I do this with AHK v2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use this (Hotkey is CTRL + SPACE):

```
^space::
{
    WinSetAlwaysOnTop -1, "A"
}
```

---

### How it works:

This script uses the `WinSetAlwaysOnTop` method to accomplish its goal. It takes several parameters, but not all of them are mandatory. `-1` tells the function to toggle the setting to the opposite of whatever it was (e.g. OFF --> ON), and `"A"` tells it to use the currently active window (whichever window has focus). You can also pass it the name of a specific window, like `"Calculator"`.

Here are some links to the relevant documentation:

- [WinSetAlwaysOnTop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/WinSetAlwaysOnTop.htm)
- [WinTitle](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/misc/WinTitle.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to toggle 'Always on top' state and alter the window title when a window's "On Top" status is changed -

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

!t:: {                          ; Alt + t
Title_When_On_Top := "! "       ; change title "! " as required
t := WinGetTitle("A")
ExStyle := WinGetExStyle(t)
If (ExStyle & 0x8) {            ; 0x8 is WS_EX_TOPMOST
    WinSetAlwaysOnTop 0, t      ; Turn OFF and remove Title_When_On_Top
    WinSetTitle (RegExReplace(t, Title_When_On_Top)), t 
    }
Else {
    WinSetAlwaysOnTop 1, t      ; Turn ON and add Title_When_On_Top
    WinSetTitle Title_When_On_Top t, t
    }
}
```

Modified from AHK v1 [code](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/94627-button-for-always-on-top/?p=596509).